# Passing custom attribute of product using sessions woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, session, woocommerce

I am trying to get a custom attribute of a product `'advance-payment' and 'post_title'` to another page using session. `post_title` gets passed but the custom attribute `advance-payment` does not. `advance-payment` is printed on simple.php but not on custom_form.php.

simple.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['post_title_form'] = $product->post->post_title;
$ca_advance_value = $product->get_attribute('advance-payment');
$_SESSION['post_advance_form']=$ca_advance_value;
//attribute is echoed here
echo "Test " . $ca_advance_value;
```

custom_form.php

```
<?php
session_start();
/* Template Name: CustomFormPage */ 
//is displayed
echo "TEST 1: " .$_SESSION['post_title_form'];
//not displayed
echo "TEST 2: ".$_SESSION['post_advance_form'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom detail to woo commerce session by below hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_custom_data_vase', 10, 2 );
    function add_cart_item_custom_data_vase( $cart_item_meta, $product_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;            
        $cart_item_meta['post_title'] = 'post title';
        $cart_item_meta['post_advance_form'] = 'Advance Payment';
        return $cart_item_meta; 
    }
```

by below code you can get cart item from cart session on your custom_form.php:

```
global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
    foreach($items as $item => $values) {           
        $post_title = $values['post_title'];
        $post_advance_form = $values['post_advance_form'];
    }
```

Comment: i have a custom button beside add to cart button on simple.php that takes to another form. i dont need data from the cart. i need custom attribute from simple.php then pass it to custom_form.php

Comment: you can use ajax or js function for pass variable to that file.but i think it is good to pass data with cart session so you can use it anywhere with use of default woo commerce functions.